# How to combine multiple data csv files in to single data frame?

Tags: r

I am having multiple csv files imported(files all are in same directory) into R with different number of columns.How can I combine them in to single data frame?

[image: one category of file]
[image: Second category of file]

I would like to have a single dataframe like biomarkers and allclinical.

Doing Column bind I will end up with a huge number of columns where as with row bind 
null values and data redundancy would occur.

whats the best way to deal with this solution.
regards,
akshay

Comment: do they all have the same headings? What is the structure of the contents? If they are the same, read them all in, then use `rbind` or `merge` to join them all

Comment: @RAB no they donot have same headings they are different

Answer (score 2):

use

```
library(gtools)
df_combines <- smartbind(df1,df2,df3......)
```

good thing about gtools is that it will append all the data with same column name and only if the column name does not match it will add a new column to the final combined data frame .

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.